# Identity Server 4 - Connecting Multiple 3rd Party Apps

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm trying to determine if identity server 4 can achieve the following.

**Scenario**

We have an app called 'Coffee Bomb' which, when a user is going for a coffee they smash a big red button on their desk, this sends people in their team a message through Slack or MS Teams to tell them that the colleague is going for coffee...they can then reply with 'get me an espresso!'  which collates it into a shopping list.

CoffeeBomb has a Slack and Teams App setup to allow API access.
There may be more connections in the future.

Bob signs up to CoffeeBomb with a local username and password.
He wants to connect to Slack so clicks "Add Slack".
This takes him through the Slack authentication flow for his slack workspace and returns a token. The token is associated with Bob so the app can send messages on his behalf.

Later on, he adds MS Teams and authenticates with Office 365 so he can send the message through teams as well.

CoffeeBomb is also a Bot App that can send proactive messages to anyone in the organisation so needs consent to be able to send anyone in bobs organisation a message.

‐---------------

**Previously**

Previously we've developed similar code to connect to products like Xero, Quickbooks and other 3rd party products.

We wrote the code from scratch to do the flow and store the token in a custom store.
The store had the App the User and the Token.

**Before we Begin**

We are building from scratch, the old code is now outdated.

I can't help thinking that IS4 has a majority of this functionality built-in. But I'm not across it enough to understand. So I'm trying to determine:

```
- If it is possible/appropriate to use IS4 for this scenario

- Which parts if ID4 to use if any.
```

Any ideas or pointers would be great.

Chris

Comment: OK, so an update - I'm currently looking at a number of projects. 
IdentityModel.AspNetCore
AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers
Microsoft.Web.Identity
Although these do not fully implement OOTB I think IdentityModel.AspNetCore can be extended to work.